# Upload Video to Facebook via video-graph.facebook iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am trying to upload a video. I have saved my video file to an MP4 file as follows:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chatVideo-%d.mp4",arc4random()%1000];
NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset2 presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = videoURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
NSData *videodata =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

I call the graph API for upload to Facebook:

```
[parameters setValue:videoData forKey:@"source"];

    [parameters setValue:thumbData forKey:@"thumb"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                       parameters:parameters
                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if ([error.userInfo[FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode] isEqual:@200]) {
             NSLog(@"permission error");
         }
     }];
```

But I receive this error:

> Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah,after a long time I have find out answer:

```
[parameters setValue:videoData forKey:@"source"];
```

It must be:

```
[parameters setValue:videoData forKey:@"video.mp4"];
```

I hate Facebook docs ==!.

Comment: wtf… I had the same problem and was trying to do manual form multipart/form encoding and what not… in the end it was just changing `source` with `video.mp4`. Where did you find this, if you remember? (curiosity).

Comment: @MartínMarconcini I reference to this source: https://github.com/lucascorrea/SCFacebook

Comment: thanks, the Facebook Documentation aims to be very complete, but it has been clearly written by different people/teams and sometimes is a mess.

Comment: So whatever video format we use, we simply call it `video.{format}` ? e.g. MOV videos will become `[parameters setValue:videoData forKey:@"video.mov"];` AVI format will become `[parameters setValue:videoData forKey:@"video.avi"];` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Creating

to see the list of supported video types:

> 3g2, 3gp, 3gpp, asf, avi, dat, divx, dv, f4v, flv, m2ts, m4v, mkv, mod, mov, mp4, mpe, mpeg, mpeg4, mpg, mts, nsv, ogm, ogv, qt, tod, ts, vob, wmv

Ergo, check if the video is *really* a MP4 video...

Comment: You can see in code above,  I have name file is MP4 and output export is AVFileTypeMPEG4 too. :(

Comment: Make sure you submit it to `graph-video.facebook.com` and that the request is encoded as `multipart/form-data `

Comment: I follow this guide from Facebook. 
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos)

And I have checked it when it run in sdk it call graph-video.facebook.com too.